# Ember.js: How to bind event handler to dom element?

Tags: ember.js, jquery

I'm using the jquery plugin *scrollTo* to create buttons to 'jump' to particular items in a long list.  I bet there is a way to loop through each item and bind the event to it's corresponding button, but I don't know how to approach that.  Sounds like something that would occur in the view though...

**How can I bind a jQuery event to each 'item' rendered in the ember template below?**

**Ember 'items' template**

```
    <div class="buttons">
        {{#each}}<a href="#" {{bindAttr class="isActive slug"}}></a>{{/each}}
    </div>

    <section class='region region-main-upper clearfix items'>
        {{#each}}
            <div {{bindAttr class=":postcard-left :item isActive slug"}}>
                <div><img class='img-polaroid' {{bind-attr src=image}}></div>
                <div>
                    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
                    <div class="span2">
                        <span class="item-property clear-row">Cost: {{printUSD itemCost}}</span>
                        <span class="item-property clear-row">Percent: {{percentVec}}%</span>
                    </div>
                    {{render 'options' options}}
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </section>
```

**Straight javascript**

This works, but is undesirable:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // this does what I am trying to achive, but is not maintainable...

        $( "body" ).on( "click", ".solar", function(e) {
            $('.items').stop().scrollTo( '.item.solar', 800 );
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });

        $( "body" ).on( "click", ".coal", function(e) {
            $('.items').stop().scrollTo( '.item.coal', 800 );
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You can bind just one click event for all the buttons at once, and add a data attribute to set up the target for each button and scroll to that.

Comment: Yeah, that works.  Is that idiomatic?

Comment: That is the way i would do it. And if you look at many plugins they follow the same patter, you can add the selector in `data-target` attribute i.e `slug` for each button and with just one click event you can fetch the target of that clicked button and scrollTo there.